# mac app store sandboxing issues

Tags: cocoa, crash, app-store, sandbox

My app has a 3rd party executable inside of its bundle which my app communicates with via NSTask.  I was able to sandbox my app and everything works, but when I submit it to the Mac App Store I am told that I must also sandbox this executable.  Now when I do this it breaks everything and what happens is the executable crashes and the crash report reveals that a sandbox cannot be created.  This executable is in my Resources folder in my project and copies into my app when I build.  So what is the solution here?  If sandboxing the actual executable makes it crash but the App Store gives me invalid binary without sandboxing it what can I do?

Thanks,

rc

Comment: Request the developer to make it sandbox compatible?

Comment: Can you post the crash? Chances are the app is crashing when you sandbox it because it's trying to do something that it's not (sandbox) entitled to do. Easiest for you would be to sandbox it properly; baring that it shouldn't be attempting to do something that it's not entitled to do.

Comment: Thank you for the replies and fortunately yes it was something I was doing wrong.  I did not have the entitlement com.apple.security.inherit for this 3rd party executable and after I added it all was ok.  I guess the only minor thing left would be can I not write this executable to my (sandboxed) application support folder and communicate with it there?  Must I communicate with it inside of my own bundle?  Before sandboxing I used to do it this way but seems not possible with sandboxing because the operation always fails...

Comment: >> Must I communicate with it inside of my own bundle?

Comment: Are you saying yes that's the answer? :-)

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd deleted my response (decided to research it further); I haven't been able to determine any limitations on communicating with (sub)launched executables (regardless of location).

Comment: Why do you want to write an executable to your application support folder and communicate with it there? I can think of reasons why you might but they all violate the Mac App Store Review Guidelines (sections 2.16 or 2.17). Include it in your app; code sign and sandbox entitle it there and everything should be good for the store.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply and yes you're right it works fine that way.  I was used to doing it the other way in pre-sandbox days so I was wondering why it did not work since I was writing the executable to my own sandboxed location.  But thanks again for all the help much appreciated!